# How do I create another thread so that my ActionListener still listens for button press events while my planet simulation runs?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a JButton and have added an `ActionListener` to it. I also have a `SimulationPanel` class which extends `JPanel` and have an instance of it named **simulationPanel**. Both are added to a `JFrame`. Within in the **actionPerformed** method of the `ActionListener` I call `simulationPanel.startSimulation()`.

```
class StartButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(mode == MODE_DEFAULT){
            mode = MODE_SIMULATING;
            startButton.setText("Stop Simulation");
            simulationPanel.startSimulation();                              
        } else if(mode == MODE_SIMULATING){
            mode = MODE_DEFAULT;
            startButton.setText("Start Simulation");
            simulationPanel.stopSimulation();
        }
    }
}
```

The `stopSimulation()` method sets running to false.

```
public void startSimulation() {
    running = true;
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(running){
        time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if(time - time2 > 1000/60){
            for(int i = 0; i < planets.size(); i++) {
                planets.get(i).setLocation(planets.get(i).getNewLocation());
            }
            this.paintImmediately(0, 0, 950, 680);
            time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
}
```

This sets the new location of my planets and repaints the screen every 60th of a second.

The problem is that once it has entered the while(running) loop the `ActionListener` no longer responds to the button being pressed and therefore `stopSimulation()` can't be called. How would I go about creating a new thread that makes the button able to respond while simulation is running?

[The entire program](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/488eaa8bbed6a442c39e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course, because your start simulation is blocking your main thread.

I suggest you use Swing Timer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: Technically, it's not blocking the "main thread", the "main thread" typically refers to the thread which started your application (as called from the JVM), the OP is blocking the Event Dispatching Thread - just removes confusion

Comment: Thank you! I've spent hours trying to figure this out and this solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Swing is a single threaded environment, if you block the Event Dispatching Thread, then it can't process the Event Queue, which involves processing user input and reaping events.

When you need to execute long running tasks, you should offload the task to another thread.

Just remember, Swing is also not thread safe, this means that you should NEVER create or modify the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

There are tools you can use to make your life easier in this respect.

You could use a `SwingWorker`, which would allow you to run the long running/blocking tasks in the background, but use the `publish`/`process` methods to send updates to the UI which does not violate the single thread rules of Swing

You could use a Swing `Timer`, which would allow you schedule regular callbacks which are executed within the context of the EDT, making it safe to update the UI from within

You could use a plain old `Thread` and use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to synchronise updates with the EDT, but I'm not a fan of this approach is its a pain to pass stateful information through

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for explaining what I was doing wrong in so much detail. It really helps me to understand why my method of doing it didn't work. :)